# How to display ArrayList items from java in jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jstl

I have generated an Arraylist, where I get items from database row by row. I want to display the values in jsp, but I don't know how to bind jsp to java.

In java class, listBook is an Arraylist of type BookBean.

BookDao class:

```
public  ArrayList<BookBean> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
```

....

```
System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getId()); ->display id of first row
System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getTitle()); ->display title of first row
System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getAuthor());
```

In my Controller class, i have:

```
    public String showBooks(Model bookModel){
        bookModel.addAttribute("bookAttribute", new BookDao());
        return "book-list";
    }
```

I want to print the results of listBook in jsp by using the Model from the Controller. How can I do that?

```
BookDao:
public  ArrayList<BookBean> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
 public void generateBookList() {
        try {
            Connection connection = ConnectToDatabase.createConnection();
            if (connection != null) {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from book ");
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    BookBean bookBean = new BookBean(resultSet.getInt("id_book"), resultSet.getString("title"), resultSet.getString("author"), resultSet.getString("publishDate"), resultSet.getInt("quantity"), resultSet.getString("bookPrice"));
                    listBooks.add(bookBean);
                } }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

BookController to open the jsp page "book-list.jsp":

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @RequestMapping("/showBooks")
    public String showBooks(Model bookModel){
        bookModel.addAttribute("bookAttribute", new BookDao());
        return "book/book-list";
    }
}
```

I want to access the "listBooks" in jsp trough the Model created in the controller. I was thinking of jstl, but I cannot manage to write the code accordingly.

Comment: Post your jsp page

Answer (score 1):

You can use jstl core tag `<c:forEach>`. If you need loop over your list you can do something like this:

*In your **BookController** pass your list to the model:*

```
 model.addAttribute("bookList", yourList);
```

***In JSP:***

```
...
<c:forEach items="${bookList}" var="book"> 
${book.id}  <%-- BookBean fields that you want print out--%>
${book.title}
<%-- another fields --%>
</c:forEach>
...
```

[see official oracle documentation for more detail](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakm)

Answer (score 0):

On a JSP page simply do the following:

```
<%
   out.println(listBooks.get(0).getId()); ->display id of first row
   out.println(listBooks.get(0).getTitle()); ->display title of first row
   out.println(listBooks.get(0).getAuthor());
%>
```

Comment: I was thinking of accessing the list through the Model bookModel from the Controller... How can I do that?

Comment: Please post the code of `Model` and `BookDao` classes also and explain your intent little more clearly.

Comment: I think you need to simplify stuffs a little bit. You need to create your Model and Controller properly. Read the following article for understanding Model View Controller concept: https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp

Comment: Your controller should be a Servlet.